# TeXShop one window mode not working after update to version 4.54

Tags: texshop, macos

I have macOS Catalina Version 10.15.7. On uploading TeXShop version 4.54, "one
window" mode stopped working, a blank page appears on the source side of the window.
I have tried recompiling the LateX file and restarting my computer. The "Separate Windows"
Option in TeXShop Preview preferences does work still.

Comment: Please go back to 4.53. There will be an update to 4.54 which has this problem fixed. By the way, you should be a bit more specific about what "stopped working" means.

Comment: Could we have "one window mode", with horizontal split, in a future version? Thx.

Answer (score 1):

TeXShop 4.55, which corrects your problem, is now available. You can update via the `TeXShop->Check for Updates…` menu item.